# StreamingOutput with Jersey not working. Behaves as block

Tags: jersey

I need to stream records as they are available. Hence i have

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class StreamingOutputImpl extends RetrieverResource implements StreamingOutput {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StreamingOutputImpl.class);
    private OutputStream os;

    public StreamingOutputImpl(final RequestParameters parameters, final String basePath) {
        super(parameters, basePath);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        this.os = os;
        read();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeRecord(final GenericRecord record) {
        try {
            Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
            writer.write(record.toString());
            writer.flush();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while write record " + record, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming i have 100 records, and writeRecord() is invoked 100 times. I see the output in browser (with @GET and @POST) only after 100 th record and not after every record.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check the data that is being exchanged between the browser & the server using firebug.

Probably this might be browser specific behavior to render data only when t he server closes the output stream to render it to the GUI .

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. Its only the browser (FF and Chrome) that is rendering all the data at once. WIth curl i see data rendered in streaming fashion.